# Android Development, how does this line of code become produced?

Tags: android

i'm reading this android dev book and im stuck understanding how this line of code is error free (please keep in mind i've gotten rid of some code because for more focus on this part.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutToInflate, ViewGroup parent, Bundle saveState)
    {
        View v = layoutToInflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_fragment,parent,false);

        return v;
    }
```

from what i believe, i need a method that returns a view because the Class extends from a Fragment class, not an activity so i have to explicitly find the view, the parameters are straight forward what i dont understand is how we create a view and set it equal to layoutToInflate...false;

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/)

Answer (score 1):

`layoutToInflate` is a variable of `LayoutInflater` and R.layout.`activity_main_fragment` is the name of the layout file to be inflated.

Comment: Names of variables don't make a difference

Comment: Yeah both are of type Bundle

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding what the concepts of `Fragment`s are. They reside inside an `Activity`. If a `Fragment` has a UI, it needs the parent `Activity` to also have a UI. That also means `Fragments` have a `ViewParent`belonging to an `Activity`. This parent is given to the `Fragment` by the `ViewGroup parent` argument. So when creating a `Fragment` with a UI, you need to inflate the layout belonging to your `Fragment` and pass it to the `Activity`, which adds it to the `ViewGroup parent`. So that's why you get a `LayoutInflater` to inflate your `Fragment`'s view:

```
View v = layoutToInflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_fragment,parent,false);
```

Afterwards you return it to give it to the parent `Activity`.